# How to group a data frame by a time interval in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, dataframe

I have a data frame `df`

```
            Date        Mobile_No      Amount            Time    .....
121526  2014-12-24        739637       200.00           9:44:00
121529  2014-12-28        199002       500.00           9:49:44
121531  2014-12-10        813770       100.00           9:50:41
121536  2014-12-09        178795       100.00           9:52:15
121537  2014-12-09        178795       100.00           9:52:24
```

having `Date` and `Time` of type `datetime64` and `object`. I need to group this data frame by time interval of 5 minutes and `Mobile_No`. My expected output is the last two rows should be counted as one (Same `Mobile_No` and time interval is less than 5 minutes).

Is there any way to achieve this?

First I thought to combine `Date` and `Time` column and make timestamp and then use it as index and apply `pd.TimeGrouper()`, but this doesn't seem to work

```
>>>import datetime as dt
>>>import pandas as pd
...

>>> df.apply(lambda x: dt.datetime.combine(x['Date'], dt.time(x['Time'])), axis=1)
```

gives the error

```
'an integer is required', u'occurred at index 121526'
```

Comment: If you combined the date and time and set this to index then you can `resample` to 5mins

Comment: @EdChum; Yeah, that's can also do the work but `dt.time` do not takes argument in the given format `hh:mm:ss` and that's why I am getting the error.

Comment: I don't understand if you have a datetimeindex then you just call `df.resample('5min')`

Comment: @EdChum; I don't have. I have to create this index but I am getting an error as mentioned in question.

Comment: What are the dtypes of 'Date' and 'Time' columns? edit your question with output from `df.info()`

Comment: @EdChum; I already added the data types of both columns.

Comment: OK, convert the Time column first and then combine: `df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time']).dt.time  df.apply(lambda row: datetime.datetime.combine(row['Date'], row['Time']), axis=1)`

Comment: @EdChum; Giving the same error.

Comment: Sorry is 'Date'` already a datetime64 or not, your question states Mobile_no is not 'Date;

Comment: I can't reproduce this, it works for me using the code snippet I posted as a comment

Answer (score 1):

Can you not convert to string, concat the strings and parse the format in to_datetime if you are having issues:

```
df['Time']=df['Time'].astype(str)
df['Date']=df['Date'].astype(str)
df['Timestamp'] = df['Date'] +' ' + df['Time']
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df['Timestamp'], format='%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S')
```

from there you can resample or us pd.Grouper as required.